# Replace all numeric values with NaN Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
         'Price': [500, 400, 0,450,750,0,0,890,0,0,415,0],
         'Quantity': [1200,1700,0,330,500,0,0,120,300,0,50,0],
         'Value': [600000,680000,0,148500,350000,0,0,106800,0,0,20750,0]}

df = pd.dataframe(data)
```

I want to replace all the numeric values (i.e. those in columns Year, Price, Quantity, Value) with NaN but I can't figure out a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and set missing values:

```
df[df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns] = np.nan
```

Or if possible some rows has numeric or numeric saved like strings use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for test them with [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for set `NaN`s:

```
df = df.where(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna())
print (df)
    Region       Country Product  Year  Price  Quantity  Value
0   Africa  South Africa     ABC   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
1   Africa  South Africa     ABC   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
2   Africa  South Africa     ABC   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
3   Africa  South Africa     ABC   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
4   Africa  South Africa     XYZ   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
5   Africa  South Africa     XYZ   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
6   Africa  South Africa     XYZ   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
7   Africa  South Africa     XYZ   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
8     Asia         Japan     DEF   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
9     Asia         Japan     DEF   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
10    Asia         Japan     DEF   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
11    Asia         Japan     DEF   NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN
```